# initialize an ec2 instance using data in s3

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

During the startup of a Linux AMI, I would like to download some data (like the sun java libraries and some proprietary software) from an S3 bucket while initializing my EC2 connection. I notice that one way to do this is to use s3cmd. BUT, how do I get the configuration file for s3cmd .s3cfg from S3?

Also, let me also know if there is a better way to connect to S3 storage during init.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's something live java libraries, that I imagine you can make them public on your S3 bucket why not use http requests and `curl` or `wget`?

EDIT:
Personally I'd use S3 python libraries (choose another language if you don't like python) and write a custom script that includes my access key (if you'd be distributing your code you need to make sure how you handle the security keys) and fetches the files that I need.

I use this:  http://aws.amazon.com/code/134

Comment: There are libraries that I don't want to make public.

Comment: if you are talking about boto. Even that needs a configuration file. But I suppose that is smaller. Anyway I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: with a library like http://aws.amazon.com/code/134 you can do all the basic functions (like uploading and downloading files from buckets) and the only thing you need to provide is your security credentials (which is not the easiest thing but workable)

Answer (score 2):

Getting AWS credentials (and other secrets) onto an EC2 instance and keeping them on the instance securely is a challenging problem.  The best solution depends on the application and the environment of the project.

Shlomo Swidler wrote an extensive article studying this issue:

> http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/08/how-to-keep-your-aws-credentials-on-ec2.html

A year later he followed up with a different approach which has other advantages:

> http://shlomoswidler.com/2010/07/storing-aws-credentials-on-an-ebs-snapshot-securely.html